# Ember hook callback

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have the following example:
http://emberjs.jsbin.com/zubahafutu/1/edit?html,js,output

The idea of `route-action` is from @rwjblue.

Clicking of the button triggers the `delete` action on application route. I send a function as a parameter to `delete`. This should run before the delete happens. So far so good, `beforeDelete` gets called, now the actual deleting should happen. I pass the `performDelete` function as a parameter, and it is called.

**The problem**

When `performDelete` gets called it loses its context. `this` points to `window`. I can not call `this.get('foo')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` is getting lost when you pass the function in `args.beforeDelete(this.get('performDelete'));` inside the `delete` action. To fix this and make sure `performDelete` is called in the right context you can do one of two things:

```
args.beforeDelete(this.performDelete.bind(this));
```

Or:

```
args.beforeDelete(() => { this.performDelete(); });
```

Comment: Minor point, but although `this.get('methodName')` will work, it is more common to just say `this.methodName`.